# Windows Forms WebBrowser: CTRL+F Search doesn't find anything

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

In our C# application, we have a form that pops up with a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control. When I click into the WebBrowser control and press CTRL+F, a search box opens.

But when I type something into the searchbox and press ENTER, nothing is being found.

How can I get search to work?

Comment: Are you using Delphi or Visual Studio? Have you embedded the WebBrowser into the dialog box?

Comment: Visual Studio. Yes, it's embedded.

Comment: It is directly put into a form. The Enter is received correctly, and I can also click the "Find" button with the mouse. In both cases, no results are being found even though the text should clearly be available on the page.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer, you can mark it if it helps you. If this still doesn't solve your issue please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you mean, you mean to use a search engine in Webbrowser, but the page jumps into blank. If my understanding is wrong, please let me know.

You can use the following code before loading webbrowser:

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

In addition, if the above code does not work, let me know.

There is also a spare scheme that you can use Cefsharp.winForms, just search in Nuget